# Aero Glass borders on popup windows in C#

Tags: c#, popup, border, aero

I would like to create pop-up windows (of a fixed size) like this:

[image: pop-up windows]

in my application using C#. I've looked into NativeWindow but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. I want a window to behave exactly like the volume control or "connect to" window in Windows 7.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this:

```
if (m.Msg == 0x84 /* WM_NCHITTEST */) {
    m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
    return;
}
base.WndProc(ref m);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using WinForms, create a form and set the following:

```
Text = "";
FormBorderStyle = Sizable;
ControlBox = false;
MaximizeBox = false;
MinimizeBox = false;
ShowIcon = false;
```

**Edit:**

This does require the window be sizable, but you can cheat at that a little. Set the MinimumSize and MaximumSize to the desired size. This will prevent the user from resizing.

As Jeff suggested, you can also do this in CreateParams:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        unchecked
        {
            cp.Style |= (int)0x80000000;    // WS_POPUP
            cp.Style |= 0x40000;            // WS_THICKFRAME
        }
        return cp;
    }
}
```

In both cases, however, you'll still get a sizing cursor when you hover over the edges. I'm not sure how to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to capture some kind of window messages to disable the cursors?

Thanks

Comment: @codethis: I looked around a bit, and didn't find anything. There's bound to be a way, though.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the resizing cursor by canceling WM_SETCURSOR.

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x20)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                return;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

That does it but leaves a weird side effect - the first time you hover over a border, the wait cursor shows up.  Then when you move it into the client area it works correctly.  Not sure how to fax that...

Answer (score 2):

In your CreateParams specify WS_POPUP and WS_THICKFRAME.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the sizing cursors over the borders handle `WM_NCHITTEST` and when over the borders return `HTBORDER`.